# How to get value from map

Tags: java

I have one map file

```
 Map<String,Object> personData = procReadData.execute(in);
```

The data is coming from this is

```
{CUR_GENERIC=[{PROPOSAL_NUMBER=1, TITLE=test proposal, LEAD_UNIT_NAME=University, FULL_NAME=test, STSTUS_CODE=Pending, DOCUMENT_TAKEN_BY=user1 qa, UPDATE_TIMESTAMP=2015-12-28 00:00:00.0, UPDATE_USER=test}]}
```

How to get `PROPOSAL_NUMBER` from that result.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: problem seems not to be to convert to JSON, but to work with the converted object

Comment: @P.J.Meisch: Unless I'm mistaken, the dupe covers the basics of that as well.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: the dupe has a lot of good information about different libraries that can be used to convert JSON in better ways than just using a Map. But we don't know if the OP can change the conversion implementation ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You should check what type the result of

```
personData.get("CUR_GENERIC");
```

is (use a debugger for this if you have no documentation available). It's probably a list or an array of Map<String, Object> depending on what tool was used to convert the JSON data to a Java map. Get the first entry of this list or array and then use `get("PROPOSAL_NUMBER")` to retrieve the entry you want.

Comment: When use personData.get("CUR_GENERIC"); Result is [{PROPOSAL_NUMBER=1, TITLE=test proposal, LEAD_UNIT_NAME=University, FULL_NAME=test, STSTUS_CODE=Pending, DOCUMENT_TAKEN_BY=user1 qa, UPDATE_TIMESTAMP=2015-12-28 00:00:00.0, UPDATE_USER=test}] But when I use get("PROPOSAL_NUMBER") result is null.Didnot get data

Comment: what data type has the returned value of `personData.get()`? How do you see what the result is? Could you please add the java code you use to extract the values to your question?

Comment: Iam using spring jdbc template for calling          procedureprocReadData = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource).withProcedureName("GET_EPAWS_PERSON_DETAILS")
    .declareParameters(new SqlParameter("AV_USER_NAME", OracleTypes.VARCHAR));
  SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("AV_USER_NAME", principal.getName());
   Map<String,Object> personData = procReadData.execute(in);                                                                             logger.debug("|__PersonData=="+personData.get("CUR_GENERIC"));     With in this I need to get PROPOSAL_NUMBER

Comment: Result is [{PROPOSAL_NUMBER=1, TITLE=test proposal, LEAD_UNIT_NAME=University, FULL_NAME=test, STSTUS_CODE=Pending, DOCUMENT_TAKEN_BY=user1 qa, UPDATE_TIMESTAMP=2015-12-28 00:00:00.0, UPDATE_USER=test}] With in this I need to get PROPOSAL_NUMBER

Comment: can you show the output of `logger.debug(personData.get("CUR_GENERIC").getClass().getCanonicalName());`?

Comment: Output is java.util.ArrayList

Comment: then `((ArrayList)personData.get("CUR_GENERIC“)).get(0).get("PROPOSAL_NUMBER")` should do. With this expression, you cast the result to ArrayList, get the first element of it and then access this element's PROPOSAL_NUMBER entry. I assume, that the ArrayList contains Map<String, Object> entries.